# Error with D3 data.map function

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to load a csv file with x and y coordinates and create circles with that coordinates. I've understood how to load a csv file and i can log coordinates in the console but I don't understand why the log function return Not_a_number when i try to create circles. Is there a problem with mine data.map function? Thanks

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /* No style rules here yet */       
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Width and height
    var w = 900;
    var h = 500;
    var padding = 20;
    var dataset = [];

    d3.csv("dataset.csv", function(data) {
      dataset = data.map(function(d,i) { 
        //THIS WORKS
        console.log(d);
        console.log(i);
        return [ +d["x-coordinate"], +d["y-coordinate"] 
        ]; });


    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
            //THIS DOESNT WORK
            console.log(d);
            return d[0];
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d[1];
       })
       .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d[1];
       })

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the `dataset` after it has been asynchronously loaded inside `d3.csv`.

The code inside `d3.csv` is executed **asynchronously**, meaning it would run only after the file has been loaded, it is not guaranteed to run before the code below it.

```
d3.csv("dataset.csv", function(data) {
  dataset = data.map(function(d,i) { 
    //THIS WORKS
    console.log(d);
    console.log(i);
    return [ +d["x-coordinate"], +d["y-coordinate"] 
    ]; });

  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(dataset)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
          //THIS DOESNT WORK
          console.log(d);
          return d[0];
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d[1];
     })
     .attr("r", function(d) {
          return d[1];
     })
     .text("hello world");

});
```

Alternatively, create a method and pass `dataset` into that method inside `d3.csv`.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the answer but now, when I log coordinates from "cx" it says Nan like if it has no value. I guess that d[0] it's not the right  way to select the attribute of the element in the dataset but I cant figure out how to do.

Comment: try logging `data` and `dataset` before `//Create SVG element`, and add that to the question, I think you map function has some problems.

Comment: okay thanks, I changed my question. I hope someone will help!

Comment: I solved the problem changing the return of the map function:  
 return [ +d["x"], +d["y"]